# Email not sent for reseting password function

Tags: php, email, symfony, fosuserbundle

I have a problem with FOSUSERBUNDLE and the reset password function. The resetting email is not sent in prod mode. (But the registration mail is sent without problems).

I have this error in my app/logs/prod.log but i don't know how to fix it.

```
[2014-12-21 13:26:34] request.INFO: Matched route "fos_user_resetting_send_email" (parameters: "_controller": "FOS\UserBundle\Controller\ResettingController::sendEmailAction", "_route": "fos_user_resetting_send_email") [] []
[2014-12-21 13:26:34] security.INFO: Populated SecurityContext with an anonymous Token [] []
[2014-12-21 13:26:34] security.DEBUG: Write SecurityContext in the session [] []
[2014-12-21 13:26:35] app.ERROR: Exception occurred while flushing email queue: Expected response code 250 but got code "", with message "" [] []
```

Can anybody help me please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem. It seems this bug happens when configures a part of the parameters. The documentation [here](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/emails.md) explains how to configure independently the two mail sending options, but also how to configure both simultaneously. It's this last point that caused my bug. I had just configured a part of the two options instead of both.

Thank you anyway, and if it can be useful to someone later ...

Comment: can you post the configuration that you originally had as well as what you changed in the configuration to get it to work?

Comment: (i had just configured the parameters of the registration but not for the resseting)